# What is the IQ plane?

Tags: quantum-state, superconducting-quantum-computing, state-tomography

I struggle to find any information on Nielsen and Chuang or similar texts on the exact definition of the so-called **IQ plane** (I think this is a notion closely related to solid state quantum computers such as transmon).

**Can you provide a simple explanation of what the IQ plane or recommend some references that clearly explain it and its relation to the estimation of quantum states when one performs quantum state tomography?**

Answer (score 3):

IQ is an abbreviation for In-phase and Quadrature phase components of the signal. Whenever a qubit state ie. Z observable is read using a system such as resonator, the phase and amplitude of the resonator at a given frequency of signal changes depending on the qubits state. This change hence creates a change in the IQ plane. Using this measurement technique, quantum tomographies are performed.

Comment: can you provide with a reference?

Comment: Perhaps in sup E.10 and E.11 of Kelly, J. S. Fault-Tolerant Superconducting Qubits, University of California, Santa Barbara, 2015. https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~martinisgroup/theses/Kelly2015.pdf.